# Apply format in a paragraph with multiple fonts

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my docs I use either Arial or Courier New (for code) and sometimes both in the same paragraph. As I share my docs with other people, they tend to use other fonts as well but it is important to keep it aligned, that;s why I am trying to create a macro that will turn all non-Courier New text into Arial and into the correct font size (11).

I face 2 problems with what I have achieved so far:

1. In paragraphs with mixed fonts it tends to change the whole paragraph (including the code) to Arial, while i need it to change only the non-code text
2. It changes the font size not only in the body text but in the headings as well.

I think I'm using incorrectly the objects of Word (I'm used in working in Excel) but I can't find anywhere online any clues. Can anyone help me please?

```
Sub CorrectFont()
    Dim p As paragraph
    Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)

    Application.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do
        If p.Range.Font.Name <> "Courier New" Then
           p.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
           p.Range.Font.Size = 11
        End If
        Set p = p.Next
    Loop Until p Is Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you try this code in Excel where you have a cell with two fonts, you will get the same issues as in word.

Comment: So, what are you proposing as a solution?

Comment: My post was mainly aimed to point out that you would find the same situation in Excel. As for Word, I'm afraid that too long time has passed since I last played with VBA in word, so I can't really give you a very focused solution. And still... I do remember that there is a way to search for text with specific format (like font and font size). It may be worth to google a little bit on Word specific search VBA function and see how to search for specific formats. Sorry I cannot be more helpful. Good luck!!

Comment: You can find the Microsoft documents for Word, and it's object model, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837519.aspx).  These docs are a gold mine of information.

Comment: I used the excel example because the objects are way more simpler there  Right now I have a paragraph and I want to edit the next object in the hierarchy which should be individual words. In excel it could be done easily by switching from range to cell. I've been searching it all day and still can't find a way to do it.. Anyway, thank you for taking time to consider it :)

Comment: Thank you @destination-data it is a very helpful library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @destination-data 's inputs I reached a final form of the code. I present it here for anyone that might be interested.

Thank you again!

```
Sub AlignFont()
Dim wd As Range

Application.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Check each word, one at a time.
For Each wd In ActiveDocument.Words

    'On objects like Contents it may create an error and crash
    On Error Resume Next
        If wd.Font.Name <> "Courier New" And wd.Style = "Normal" Then
            wd.Font.Name = "Arial"
        End If

        'To avoid any header that may have a "Normal" style
        If wd.Font.Bold = False Then
            wd.Font.Size = 11
        End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check each individual word, like so:

```
' Replaces non-Arial fonts with Arial.
' Exception: Courier New is not replaced.
Sub AlignFont()
    Dim wd As Range

    ' Check each word, one at a time.
    For Each wd In ActiveDocument.Words

        If Not (wd.Font.Name = "Arial" Or wd.Font.Name = "Courier New") Then

            wd.Font.Name = "Arial"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that covers 1 part of the question. Do you have any idea about how I can restrict it to not affect the headings?

Comment: Sorry I missed the section about the headers.  How do you know what is a header?  Do you use the built-in styles?

Comment: Yes I have created different custom styles for the headers and the rest of the text. I tried adding an if in the statement for the styles but it didn't seem to work... 

If Selection.Range.Font.Name <> "Courier New" And Selection.Range.Style = "Normal" Then...

Comment: I like your appraoch.  This should work.  You should check the styles are named as expected, Word does not always do this!  To check: Highlight one word.  Run this code `Msgbox(Application.Selection.Words(1).Style)`.